# PostgreSQL + PG_Monz (Zabbix) DB size too large > 1073741824

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I an new to Postgres (9.3 on Ubuntu 14.04) monitoring and I have been using Zabbix/PG_monz.

I am seeing errors that my database has "too many temp bytes" and that my database is "too large". My actual backup files are 400 MB daily.

I am wondering if anyone is familiar with PG_Monz or just what this error might be about. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer with regards to how and why this is happening. 
PG_Monz is using the following query to track temp bytes:

```
UserParameter=psql.db_temp_bytes[*],psql -h $1 -p $2 -U $3 -d $4 -t -c "select temp_bytes from pg_stat_database where datname = '$5'"
```

However, this select statement does not show the current temp bytes, instead it shows an increment of all temp bytes ever created since the last stats reset. IE: It's not showing a delta over a time period which would be the accurate number.

Looking at this query and then checking the folder, I see it's empty and therefore my server actually has no temp bytes.

```
select current_setting('data_directory') || '/base/pgsql_tmp'
```

Source: https://www.marshut.net/wnsmt/postgresql-9-2-4-temp-files-never-released.html

The same goes for a DB being too large:

Zabbix threshhold is incorrect for the way PostgreSQL reports size of databases: 
See info about `select pg_database_size(dbname)`